# Extract specific element from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-lists

I have a list where I display the content of a list using angularjs, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="result in uploadLogObject[fileUpload.id].log track by $index">
      <ul>
        <div data-ng-show="result">{{result}}</div>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This means that I get a list like this:

```
* Some data1
* Some data2
* Some data3
* Some data4
```

Is it possible to take e.g the first element of the list and place outside of the list so that my list is displayed like this?

```
Some data1
* Some data2
* Some data3
* Some data4
```

I would guess you would have to do a separate `ng-repeat="result in uploadLogObject[fileUpload.id].log track by $index"` before the ng-repeat with the list and then display the first content somehow like this? `<div data-ng-show="result">{{result}}[0]</div>`

Am I wrong or on the right track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) provides a way to do this using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. :

```
  <div ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-if="$first">
    Header {{ item }}
  </div>

  <li ng-repeat-end>
    body {{ item }}
  </li>
```

Comment: Works! Although I had to add ng-if="!$first" to the ng-repeat-end since I did not want the first element inside my list aswell. Thanks!